# Break a learning barrier with Java + LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have been coding with Java and LWJGL for some time. I mainly use thebennybox's tutorials, but I can't always remember the 3D rendering. But even when I have a 3D rendering models, planes, cubes, etc. I can't get past that. I *need* a good LWJGL tutorial! I look up to Notch and I know a good bit about Minecraft's history, and wish I could code as fluently as him. I also understand a good bit of Java.

Comment: *You don't become great by trying to be great. You become great by wanting to do something, and then doing it so hard that you become great in the process - [Randall Munroe (xkcd)](http://xkcd.com/896/)* So stop with the tutorials and start with the project you want to do.

Answer (score 5):

LWJGL was my starting point for OpenGL (I since moved on to writing native C++ code), so I get where you're coming from. But what you should be looking for is good *OpenGL* tutorials, not LWJGL tutorials in specific. The LWJGL wiki should have everything you need as far as the library is concerned.

The tutorials I'm going to recommend? [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming.](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)

The examples use C++, but if you're familiar with Java, then the syntax is very similar. Then with the help of LWJGL's documentation, get at them!

I promise, they are the best tutorials on the web right now as far as OpenGL is concerned. They only go so far though, the more advanced stuff hasn't been written yet, but that's okay. Once you finish these tutorials, you should really *understand* OpenGL at a much more fundamental level, and be able to play around with it. Of course it's always nice to read up on some specific techniques used for 3D graphics, for which I recommend the [OpenGL 4.0 Shading Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/opengl-4-0-shading-language-cookbook/book). But, again, that's for when you understand the core elements, and are ready to implement over-the-top bloom, lens flare, and the like.

Any tutorials that teach you immediate mode rendering, forget them. It's outdated, and will just hurt you in the long-run. And with that said, I'd also like to note that since GLSL (the shading language) is C-like, it'd likely help to know C/C++. But, again, Java is close enough, so you should get by with just that.

As for getting Notch-like programming powers, you just need more experience. If you look at everything he's done before Minecraft, there's a lot of it. As they say, Rome wasn't built in a day...

Comment: this is a really good answer but unfortunately it's to a tutorial request which will probably soon be closed as a "how to get started" question.  +1 anyway, and welcome onboard.